# Pythonic way to check empty dictionary and empty values

Tags: python, dictionary

I am using these kind of dictionaries, they can be or totally empty like `collection_a` or contain a single one level nested dictionary which might be empty. It wont have more levels.

```
collection_a = {}
collection_b = {"test": {}}

print is_empty(collection_a)
print is_empty(collection_b)

def is_empty(collection):
    return not all(collection.values())
```

or

```
def is_empty(collection):
    return not bool(collection.values())
```

Isnt there an unique way to check if a or b have values?

You can check `all(collection_b.values())` but that wont work for collection_a where it will return True

You can also check `bool(collection_a.values())` but that wont work for collection_b where it will return True...

Isnt there an unique way to include both cases?

Comment: `if len([y.values() for x, y in collection_a.items()])): do_something()` ?

Comment: len(collection_a.values())==0 ?

Comment: I mean I want to include both cases with the same condition

Comment: Can you explain why you are doing this? What is the context?

Comment: This really feels like an XY Problem. And IMHO question is still unclear.

Comment: I think it's pretty clear, can you have an unique if condition which can check both cases instead having two ifs?

Comment: @lapinkoira. You should really post some actual code to clarify. It is actually not as clear as you imagine it to be.

Comment: I perfected the one-liner: `if len([y.values() for x, y in collection_a.items() if len(y)]): print('moo')`. This will work on any 2 level dict. And won't result in a false positive :)

Comment: "[Is] there a unique way to check if a or b have values?" sounds like you're asking for a solution that combines a test on `collection_a` with a test on `collection_b`, rather than a single expression that you can plug either one into.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I understand your concern but since people have already posted valid answers then I think it's clear enough

Comment: @lapinkoira. You might get better answers if you were to honor requests for clarification.

Comment: In my code I am using dictionaries which might be totally empty and other dictionaries which might have a nested dictionary also empty, nothing else, no other kind of dictionaries, I am trying to avoid double checking, I thought using all() or bool() as I wrote in my question but it just works for one of them, never for both at the same time

Comment: @lapinkoira. Could you edit that into your question? That is valuable information. Also, it is unclear as to whether your outer dictionary can have more than one key in it. Could you make that explicit as well?

Comment: @MadPhysicist I edited my question

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Test with `any`, since empty dicts are *falsy*:

```
>>> collection_a = {}
>>> collection_b = {"test": {}}
>>> any(collection_a.values())
False
>>> any(collection_b.values())
False
```

This assumes that the dictionary value is always a dictionary.

Comment: It's not clear this behaves correctly for other falsy values, e.g. `collection_c = {3:0}`

Comment: @Chris_Rands. I think OP implies that the first-level values will always be `dict`s, if anything.

Comment: @Chris_Rands I am not using those kind of dictionaries so it looks like "any" would work, I didnt use it because thought if "all" didnt work any wouldnt work neither but ye... it's working

Answer (score 6):

If you want to check whether the dictionary *has* values, and whether *all* the values (if any) are "truthy", just combine your two tests:

```
bool(collection) and all(collection.values())
```

(The `bool` in the first part is optional, but without it you will get an unintuitive `{}` if the dictionary is empty.)

Of course, if you only want to check whether *any* of the values in the collection are "truthy" (this is not entirely clear from your question), all you have to do is `any(collection)`, as already stated in other answers; this will at the same time also check whether the collection is non-empty.

Comment: That should be an `any`.

Comment: This fails with falsy values as well, `collection_c = {3: 0}`

Comment: @MadPhysicist No, the way I understand the question it should really be an `all`.

Comment: @Vinny Where did you read how it should behave for `0` values? Given that OP used `all`, I think that's what he wants, and he's just looking for a way to make it return `False` for an empty collection. But of course that's just my understanding of the question.

Comment: @tobias_k. Interesting point. OP's code says all, but I read the words as implying any. Hard to tell which one.

Comment: @tobias_k. OP has made a new comment that implies that there is only one key in the outer dictionary, ever. Our solutions are probably equivalent...

Comment: @tobias_k the OP didn't relate to `0`, but `0` is a legit value and I don't think it is considered empty dict in that case. That's a corner case, which makes the problem more complicated

Answer (score 3):

Because :

```
>>> dict={}
>>> not dict
True
```

So You can check like this :

```
collection_a = {"hello":1,"bye":2}
if collection_a:
    #do your stuff
    print("not empty")

collection_a = {}
if collection_a:
    print("dict is not empty")
```

if you want to check dict a or dict b then :

```
if collection_a or collection_b:
    print("not empty")
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, `bool()` in combination with [more-itertools'](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) `collapse()`:

```
import more_itertools

def has_value(thing):
    return bool(*more_itertools.collapse(thing))
```

---

```
>>> has_value({})
False
>>> has_value({''})
False
>>> has_value({0:['']})
False
>>> has_value({'test':[]})
True
```